# Custom C# server with HLS support

Tags: c#, http, video-streaming, http-live-streaming

I'm trying to build a custom C# webserver with HLS support but specifically, the HLS part does not work. Below is the code I use. I'm trying to keep it as simple as necessary. The problem is that all file types work except the ones used in the HLS protocol. The file types I experimented with are `mp4`, `xml`, `mp3`, `jpg`, `png` and pure binary data files without extensions.

```
public class LocalServer
{
    public bool runListener = true;
    private string prefix;
    private string baseDirectory = "M:/ftp backup/";

    public LocalServer(int port)
    {
        prefix = string.Format("http://+:{0}/", port);
        Thread listenerThread = new Thread(LocalServerThread);
        listenerThread.Start();
    }

    public void LocalServerThread()
    {
        HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
        listener.Prefixes.Add(prefix);
        listener.Start();
        Debug.Log(DateTime.Now.ToString(SimpleHTTPServer.dateFormat) + "<color=green>Started local web server</color>");
        while (runListener)
        {
            IAsyncResult result = listener.BeginGetContext(new AsyncCallback(ListenerCallback), listener);
            result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
        }
        listener.Close();
        Debug.Log(DateTime.Now.ToString(SimpleHTTPServer.dateFormat) + "<color=green>Stopped local web server</color>");
    }

    public void ListenerCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        HttpListener listener = (HttpListener)result.AsyncState;
        HttpListenerContext context = listener.EndGetContext(result);
        string fileNameComplete = context.Request.Url.AbsolutePath.Substring(1).Replace("%20", " "); //removing the first slash and replacing the %20 web prefix by space
        string pathComplete = baseDirectory + fileNameComplete;
        Debug.Log(DateTime.Now.ToString(SimpleHTTPServer.dateFormat) + pathComplete + " requested to LocalServer");
        using (Stream fileStream = new FileStream(pathComplete, FileMode.Open))
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[fileStream.Length];
            fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, (int)fileStream.Length);
            context.Response.ContentLength64 = fileStream.Length;
            context.Response.ContentType = SimpleHTTPServer.GetMimeType(fileNameComplete);

            //personal headers
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
            ////apache headers
            //context.Response.StatusDescription = "OK";
            //context.Response.ProtocolVersion = new Version("1.1");
            //context.Response.SendChunked = false;
            //context.Response.KeepAlive = true;
            //context.Response.AddHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
            //context.Response.AddHeader("ETag", BinarySocket.RandomString(20));
            //context.Response.AddHeader("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            //context.Response.AddHeader("Keep-Alive", "timeout=5, max=100");
            ////CORS
            //context.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            //context.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS");
            //context.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
            //context.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "86400");

            context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            context.Response.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

The SimpleHTTPServer is the class I used in my previous attempt. This class uses the mime-type dictionary form the SimpleHTTPServer class. It also uses dateFormat from the SimpleHTTPServer which is: `"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff:"`. The mime types used for HLS are: `".m3u8", "application/vnd.apple.mpegurl"` and `".ts", "video/MP2T"` which are the same as those used by apache. I commented-out the Apache and CORS response properties because it had no effect on the downloads.

The HLS streams coming from my HTTP server are not opened by some mediaplayers(media foundation, direct show). Opening it in VLC causes VLC to download every m3u8 playlist(master playlist) and sub m3u8 playlist(different resolutions/bandwidths) very slowly and only after it is done downloading all playlists, it starts to play the 4k video fragment. The resolution of the next fragment is 1440p and it keeps going down until it reaches 360p. However, playing the exact same files through a stream coming from apache or Nginx work perfectly.

Does someone know what I'm doing wrong or implementing the wrong way in order to make HLS work? I've read the HTTP Live Streaming RFC(RFC-8216) and I think I'm doing everything right required to make HLS work but it doesn't, so I must be doing something wrong. The Apple documentation describes that any HTTP server can support HLS by simply adding the mime types but doing that does not solve the issue.

EDIT: When running this code from a visual studio console application, it works, but when running this code in Unity, Unity blocks until the download is complete. Seems like a threading issue but it all runs on a separate thread right? Or is the listener callback executed on the main thread?

EDIT 2: The listener is executed on a separate thread so something else blocks the main thread while files are being downloaded. Apparently no matter whats being downloaded, the thread blocks, everything else was simply being downloaded too fast to notice the blocking. HLS is actually downloading the master playlist, then 6 different playlists then all 15 video fragments after eachother. Likely because I was using `result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();` in the thread which makes it impossible to have multiple parallel downloads. I replaced it by `Thread.Sleep(10);` so I can have parallel downloads. It does not solve the blocking issue.

EDIT 3: Blocking appears to happen because the program is uploading and downloading simultaneously. Both sides of the code(downloading/uploading) work well in separate programs but the facts that both happen in one program makes the unity thread block.

EDIT 4: Blocking happens only with DirectShow, not with MediaFoundation

Comment: Did you found a solution?

Comment: Nope, sorry, I stopped working there shortly after